# Did Richard Feynman say "Philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds."

Tags: quotes

A quote that is often attributed to Richard Feynman is

> Philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds.

Is there any evidence to suggest that Richard Feynman actually said this?

Examples are [here](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/philo/philosophers_are_just_lazy_scientists./) and [here](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=3On91NcQbNMC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22Philosophy+of+science+is+about+as+useful+to+scientists+as+ornithology+is+to+birds%22&source=bl&ots=2MVdlaqTd6&sig=fbVqZQZ-FPjbRGnaqwbBcC7RGYQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgg-XmheXSAhViLcAKHSbAAcU4ChDoAQgsMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Philosophy%20of%20science%20is%20about%20as%20useful%20to%20scientists%20as%20ornithology%20is%20to%20birds%22&f=false).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The oldest two sources of the quote says it is anonymous, [A Re- examination of the Metaphysical Foundations of Modern Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=32NUq2m-LzkC&q=%22scientists%20as%20ornithology%20%22&dq=%22scientists%20as%20ornithology%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKuYqSoOXSAhVMwiYKHXIuDAYQ6AEIIzAC) (1991), :

> the anonymous remark that "philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds."

and [Process Thought: Its Value and Meaning to Me](https://www.pdcnet.org/pdc/bvdb.nsf/purchase?openform&fp=process&id=process_1990_0019_0004_0219_0229) (1990)

> It is the exceptional scientist who is interested in the philosophy of science. As one of them said,
>    "The philosophy of science is as useful to a scientist as ornithology is to birds."

It is borrowing from a quote of [Barnett Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnett_Newman) :

> aesthetics is to artists what ornithology is
>   to birds

as quoted in the 1974 article [Aesthetics - Gone with Gregor](https://ojs.lboro.ac.uk/ojs/index.php/SDEC/article/view/753)

Comment: So that is a "NO"?

Comment: @matt_black it's not a guaranteed "no".  The original question was asking for the oldest reference for the quote, but SIMEL edited out that part of OP's question.

Comment: @DavePHD, I feel that asking for the oldest available reference is a valid request.

Comment: John Barrow also mentions this quote (again without attribution) on [p. 10](https://archive.org/details/worldwithinworld00barr/page/10/mode/2up) of his 1988 book *The World Within the World*, the 1990 edition can be borrowed from archive.org